# Join column from another table with Foreign Key using JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm new to JPA and trying to understand if there's a way to make an `Entity` where one column is coming from another table that is linked by a foreign key. For example, consider the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `jobs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_jobs_users` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
);
```

Now I want to make an `Entity` for the "jobs" table that will include the `user.email`. I know I can do something like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "jobs")
public class JobEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @Formula("(select user.email FROM user WHERE user.id = user_id)")
    private String userEmail;
```

But I feel there's a way I can better leverage the foreign key relationship, but I'm not sure how. I was looking into [`@JoinColumn`](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-join-column) but was not seeing the result I wanted since the foreign key is a different column in my `Entity`. Is there a better way rather than using `@Forula` to do this?

Comment: Here's some [useful video course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Svpcn5wJ8CU)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand this. I'm sure `@JoinColumn` can accomplish the behavior you're looking for.

> I was looking into @JoinColumn but was not seeing the result I wanted since the foreign key is a different column in my Entity

Example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "jobs")
public class KronosFileEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumn = "id")
    private User user;
}
```

Then you can access the email like `job.getUser().getEmail()`

Or add a convenience method if that helps

```
public String getUserEmail() {
   return user.getEmail();
}
```

Then
`job.getUserEmail()`